# AutoFixture/AutoMoq: Unable to Create Instance (`BadImageFormatException`)

Tags: moq, autofixture, automoq

Below is a minimal example of the problem I am currently encountering:

```cs
using System.Net.WebSockets;
using AutoFixture;
using AutoFixture.AutoMoq;
using FluentAssertions;
using Xunit;

...

[Fact]
public void Test1()
{
    var fixture = new Fixture().Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization() { ConfigureMembers = true });
    var sut = fixture.Create<WebSocket>();
    sut.Should().NotBeNull();
}

[Fact]
public void Test2()
{
    var fixture = new Fixture().Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization() { ConfigureMembers = true });
    var sut = new Mock<WebSocket>().Object;
    fixture.Inject(sut);
    sut.Should().NotBeNull();
}
...
```

When I run the first test, I get the following exception:

```
AutoFixture.ObjectCreationExceptionWithPath : AutoFixture was unable to create an instance from Moq.Mock`1[System.IO.Stream] because creation unexpectedly failed with exception. Please refer to the inner exception to investigate the root cause of the failure.

Inner exception messages:
System.BadImageFormatException: An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)
```

The second test succeeds.

I would like to be able to create an instance of a class using AutoFixture which takes a `WebSocket` as a constructor parameter, without the need to inject a mock object first (ultimately, so that I can use an `AutoMoqData` attribute, and get rid of some boilerplate). Have I got any misusage or misunderstanding going on here, or would this be better placed as a GitHub issue? In the interim, is there anything I can do to work around this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You observe this issue because of the AutoFixture's factory discovery strategy. When you try to create an object of an abstract type, AutoFixture still inspects the type to find a static factory method to activate the object. In your particular case, the `WebSocket` type contains such methods, so some of them is used. It looks like it doesn't work well with auto-generated input values, so fails with an exception.

You can customize AutoFixture, to always mock the `WebSocket` type:

```
fixture.Register((Mock<WebSocket> m) => m.Object);
```

Just tested with the latest versions of products (`AutoFixture 4.5.0`, `Moq 4.10.0`) and it works like a charm.

Comment: Are you sure that this addresses the root cause of the problem? Usually, `BadImageFormatException` is caused by incompatible assembly versions. I'd expect that this problem could be resolved with an assembly redirect, but no other code. Have you tried that?

Comment: Honestly, I was unable to reproduce the original issue locally, so I'm not confident why exactly it happened :-/ I decided to suggest a solution anyway and get back to the issue only if it happens again. My guess is that `BadImageFormatException` might be also thrown by `Moq` - when proxy type is generated for some tricky system type, and later it cannot be loaded due to some issues with it.